# Basic Conditional Checking for IF statements in C

Tags: c, conditional-statements, if-statement

Can someone please explain what really goes on in this code ?
If I put the AND statement, the message wont show if  values are less than 0 or greater than 10 ... I think I must use 1 0 logic to work this out right ?
I just need someone to briefly explain it please.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){

  puts("enter number");
  scanf("%d",num);
  if(num<0 || num >10)
     puts("yay");
}
```

How is that IF statement different when AND is put :

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){

  puts("enter number");
  scanf("%d",num);
  if(num<0 && num >10)
     puts("yay");
}
```

Thanks !!

Comment: (a) You need to declare `num` and (b) you need to pass a pointer to `num` to `scanf()`, not `num` itself.  You probably could also use an introductory computer science text.

Comment: Can you think of a number that is both less than zero and greater than ten?

Comment: @James, Yes I know that, thanks for pointing them out, I just wrote down a random program here .. so missed out those ....
@walky, Nope, but I was looking for an explanation as mentioned below, thanks for the reply though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on Boolean logic:

```
true || true -> true
true || false -> true
false || true -> true
false || false -> false

true && true -> true
true && false -> false
false && true -> false
false && false -> false
```

Notice how those differ when one side is true and the other is false.

Anyway, in your test:

```
if(num<0 && num >10)
```

It's not possible for a number to both be `< 0` and at the same time be `> 10`.  Because of this, you will either evaluate `true && false` (for negative numbers), `false && false` (for numbers between 0 and 10 inclusive) or `false && true` (for numbers larger then 10).  In all those cases, the boolean logic says the answer is `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Boolean logic.

If you use || (OR), the statement is true if ANY of the conditions are met. If you use && (AND), the statement is true ONLY if ALL of the conditions are met. SO in your second example, the statement will be true if the number is BOTH smaller than 0 AND larger than 10. Clearly there is no such number.

Answer (score 2):

1) I believe you forgot some char in scanf string:

```
scanf("%d",&num);
```

2) first example will say "yay" if number is LESS THAN 0 **or** GREATER THAN 10

second example will never say "yay" b/c number must be LESS THAN 0 **and** GREATER THAN 10 **simultaneously**

Comment: THanks for the info, yeah I just type down a random program here ... thanks!